# How to speed up web page load time (CRON? Load API call in background?)

Tags: javascript, php

I made a portal page for myself that calls a 3rd party (weather) API on every load (see screenshot). This 3rd party API sometimes takes up to 10s to return data, causing the page to load unacceptably slow.

So I thought about running a CRON job every 10-15m to grab the data and cache it locally. However, that's not an ideal solution because it puts way more stress on the API provider than necessary. I also personally prefer not to use a CRON job, if possible.

The only other solution I could think of was loading the API data in the background somehow, thereby allowing the rest of the page to load while I wait for the weather data to return from the API provider. I'm not even sure what to search for to learn how to do this.

Q1. What is that "loading in the background" programming "technique" called? Give me something to search for.

Q2. Can you think of any other options for loading/caching the API data? I think a CRON job or the "JS technique" are my only options, but I've been out of the loop for a while.

[image: biffbam]

Comment: The term you're looking for might be called 'prefetching'? Check with the owners of the API, some have usage agreements that allow you to hit their API so many times an hour or so. Could be worth looking into.

Comment: 1) On the server side it would be called "prefetching" or "caching", on the client side "async" or "deferred" loading. 2) Combine async loading with a server-side cache that you only update when requested and outdated.

Comment: Commenting on my own post. You want jQuery `.load()`, `.get()` or `.ajax()`. In my case, a simple `.load()` did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at cross-domain, asynchronous AJAX calls - that's the name.

In order to do cross-domain calls you should have a PHP wrapper/proxy file on your server which you can call from your JavaScript.

The proxy file in PHP calls the API endpoint and returns some JSON.

So when user loads your page, after the HTML DOM is loaded, then the JavaScript code calls your proxy in the background and then updates HTML element when the data is downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: That's called `AJAX` ("Asynchronous Javascript and XML") or `XHR` ("XMLHttpRequest"). Load your basic page and put a placeholder where the weather information should be, then use javascript to call a PHP page in the background that fetches the API result and returns the weather information, which you can then display in the place of your placeholder.

Q2: Look into caching solutions like `memcached` or something similar (since this is your own portal that might be a good learning experience, or you could roll your own solution for something as relatively simple as this). When your PHP code needs the weather information, it first looks in the cache to see if it already has weather info and how old that info is. If it doesn't exist or is too old (e.g. > 15 minutes), it calls the 3rd party API and updates the information in the cache.

You can combine these two techniques to speed up your AJAX request, or you could update your cache with a cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Like mentioned befor! One visitor is always the bad one who gets details delayed but all others until a cache expires. 
I would checkout keywords like "php background processing" and "caching" or like mentioned: "prefetching" but "cache" is more helpful but also more results to filter.

Q2: Depens on your wishes. Always up to date? every user? every time?

Because of request limits: One user has to wait (until ajax request done). other user using a cache is a good option for me.

Other option: if no user visits. then you can catch in backgound the api for the next interval to present the new values directly :)

So: the cron can run every e.g. 5min. but you can check if the API must be requested if the cache is not expired.

Kind regards
Florian